# How do I install a relay receiver?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, relay

I have a string of lights above a tv that are controlled by a switch. But, the switch also controls a few other things. I cannot leave the switch in the on position as I do not want the lights on all the time but I would like outlets to continuously run. I bought a relay receiver and it seems pretty straight forward. I just want to establish the how to.

[image: ...]

[image: ...]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: You might be able to accomplish the same thing with some basic wiring changes at the light switch, by providing power directly to the outlets and bypassing the switch. If you are comfortable with basic wiring then provide some pictures of the wiring of the switch and we'll let you know

Comment: If you are in the US consider "The Clapper" it is available from Amazon and other retailers.  It is basically a sound activated switch.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved, for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

The "how to" is you send that rubbish back to the dark place.  It is not safe nor legal, and doesn't even fit our wiring.  You bought it in a way that circumvented the systems that assure quality, safe products in the consumer retail stream.  Don't do that with electrical gear.

Then you buy any of a wide variety of products which do that same function, work with standard radio interfaces, but much more importantly, standard plugs and sockets so you can hook them up without creating an unsafe condition.  And most importantly of all, these products follow our safety standards and have a proper UL or ETL listing (third party testing proving it).

Those include smart bulbs, smart bulb sockets which piggyback onto an Edison base, smart outlet modules that plug into a standard socket and give you a controlled socket, etc.  There's no shortage of these products.  Your local big-box stores has pages and pages of them on their website.